# PDO select WHERE (session variable)

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I would like a page to display all results corresponding with a `id_slogan` that was set randomly on a previous page. So on the first page, a random info from the DB `liste_slogans` is generated, and its id is kept in a `$_SESSION` variable :

```
<?php
    $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slogans', 'root', 'root', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT id, slogan, compagnie FROM liste_slogans ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1,1');
    header("Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
    {
        echo '<p class="apparition1" element style="color:aqua">' . ($donnees['slogan']) . ' <element style="color:transparent">' . ($donnees['id']) . '' . ($donnees['compagnie']) . '</element style></p>';
        $_SESSION['id_slogan']=$donnees['id'];
        $_SESSION['compagnie']=$donnees['compagnie'];
        $_SESSION['slogan']=$donnees['slogan']; 
    }                   
?>
```

On the other page, I want to display all the entries in the DB `entrees` which have a `id_slogan` matching with the session variable set on the first page. I have tried this and many other things, but nothing seems to work :

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slogans;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }   

    $nbid = $_SESSION['id_slogan'];
    $reponse=$bdd->query('SELECT pseudo, entree FROM entrees WHERE id_slogan = '.$nbid' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 50');

    while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch())
    {
        echo '<h4 class=resultats><strong>' . htmlspecialchars($donnees['entree']) . ' </strong></h4> <p class=resultats> ' . htmlspecialchars($donnees['pseudo']) . '</p>';
    }
    $reponse->closeCursor();
?>
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Edit : There are actually 3 pages involved in this, and I start the session on every one of them ; I end it on the last page, at the very end of it.

Comment: What is the result you get ?

Comment: I start the session on every page involved in what I've described above. I get a totally blank page when I try what I've copied in my previous message.

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world, PHP could detect you want to use sessions and just play nice, but it does not.

On your page using the session variables you are missing the line

```
session_start();
```

Place this directly under the starting `<?php` tag on both pages using the session variables (and any other ones you have)

See [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on
>   a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
>   cookie.

Comment: Yeah I already put that on each page... and I close it at the end of the final page.